# How to process a 49.000 character-long json-string into a clob in pl/sql

Tags: json, plsql, clob

I have a very long json-String with over 49k characters, so it doesn't fit in a clob. 
I have a procedure that has the json-String as a clob input. There I want to read out all values and insert them in my table. If I make the json-String smaller for testing everything works fine. But as I said, the json-String is over 49k charachters long.

The head of my Procedure looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE set_FDC_Data(in_json IN CLOB) IS
    v_json          elmos_opt.json;
    v_json_keys     elmos_opt.json_list;
    v_json_else_obj elmos_opt.json;

    v_elseNr VARCHAR(10);
    v_pce    VARCHAR(10);

    v_channel1    elmos_opt.json;
    v_protocolCh1 VARCHAR(10);
    v_portCh1     NUMBER;
    v_deviceIdCh1 NUMBER;
    v_t3Ch1       NUMBER;
    v_t1Ch1       NUMBER;
    v_t2Ch1       NUMBER;
    v_t4Ch1       NUMBER;
    v_t5Ch1       NUMBER;
    v_t6Ch1       NUMBER;
    v_t7Ch1       NUMBER;
    v_t8Ch1       NUMBER;

    v_channel2      elmos_opt.json;
    v_remoteHostCh2 VARCHAR(50);
    v_protocolCh2   VARCHAR(10);
    v_portCh2       NUMBER;
    v_deviceIdCh2   NUMBER;
    v_t3Ch2         NUMBER;
    v_t1Ch2         NUMBER;
    v_t2Ch2         NUMBER;
    v_t4Ch2         NUMBER;
    v_t5Ch2         NUMBER;
    v_t6Ch2         NUMBER;
    v_t7Ch2         NUMBER;
    v_t8Ch2         NUMBER;

    v_channel3    elmos_opt.json;
    v_deviceIdCh3 NUMBER;
    v_t3Ch3       NUMBER;
    v_t1Ch3       NUMBER;
    v_t2Ch3       NUMBER;
    v_t4Ch3       NUMBER;
    v_t5Ch3       NUMBER;
    v_t6Ch3       NUMBER;
    v_t7Ch3       NUMBER;
    v_t8Ch3       NUMBER;

    v_channel4    elmos_opt.json;
    v_deviceIdCh4 NUMBER;
    v_t3Ch4       NUMBER;
    v_t1Ch4       NUMBER;
    v_t2Ch4       NUMBER;
    v_t4Ch4       NUMBER;
    v_t5Ch4       NUMBER;
    v_t6Ch4       NUMBER;
    v_t7Ch4       NUMBER;
    v_t8Ch4       NUMBER;

    v_deviceIdHost   NUMBER;
    v_deviceIdEqp    NUMBER;
    v_deviceIdEqpBis NUMBER;
BEGIN
v_json      := elmos_opt.json(in_json);
v_json_keys := v_json.get_keys();

FOR i IN 1 .. v_json_keys.count LOOP
  v_elseNr := v_json_keys.get(i).get_string;
  v_json_else_obj := elmos_opt.json(v_json.get(v_elseNr));
  v_pce           := v_json_else_obj.get('PCE').get_string;

  v_channel1    := elmos_opt.json(v_json_else_obj.get('CHANNEL1'));
  v_protocolCh1 := v_channel1.get('PROTOCOL').get_string;
  v_portCh1 := v_channel1.get('PORT').get_number;
  v_deviceIdCh1 := v_channel1.get('DEVICE_ID').get_number;
  v_t3Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T3_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t1Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T1_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t2Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T2_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t4Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T4_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t5Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T5_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t6Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T6_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t7Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T7_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t8Ch1 := v_channel1.get('T8_TIMEOUT').get_number;

  v_channel2      := elmos_opt.json(v_json_else_obj.get('CHANNEL2'));
  v_remoteHostCh2 := v_channel2.get('REMOTE_HOST').get_string;
  v_protocolCh2 := v_channel2.get('PROTOCOL').get_string;
  v_portCh2 := v_channel2.get('PORT').get_number;
  v_deviceIdCh2 := v_channel2.get('DEVICE_ID').get_number;
  v_t3Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T3_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t1Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T1_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t2Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T2_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t4Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T4_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t5Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T5_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t6Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T6_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t7Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T7_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t8Ch2 := v_channel2.get('T8_TIMEOUT').get_number;

  v_channel3    := elmos_opt.json(v_json_else_obj.get('CHANNEL3'));
  v_deviceIdCh3 := v_channel3.get('DEVICE_ID').get_number;
  v_t3Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T3_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t1Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T1_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t2Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T2_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t4Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T4_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t5Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T5_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t6Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T6_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t7Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T7_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t8Ch3 := v_channel3.get('T8_TIMEOUT').get_number;

  v_channel4    := elmos_opt.json(v_json_else_obj.get('CHANNEL4'));
  v_deviceIdCh4 := v_channel4.get('DEVICE_ID').get_number;
  v_t3Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T3_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t1Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T1_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t2Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T2_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t4Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T4_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t5Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T5_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t6Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T6_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t7Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T7_TIMEOUT').get_number;
  v_t8Ch4 := v_channel4.get('T8_TIMEOUT').get_number;

  v_deviceIdHost := v_json_else_obj.get('DEVICE_ID_HOST').get_number;
  v_deviceIdEqp := v_json_else_obj.get('DEVICE_ID_EQP').get_number;

  IF v_json_else_obj.exist('DEVICE_ID_EQP_BIS') THEN
    v_deviceIdEqpBis := v_json_else_obj.get('DEVICE_ID_EQP_BIS').get_number;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
END setFDC_DATA;
```

There was a post where it was suggested that the clob should be divided in chunks, but how if the clob is an input parameter and how can I do it in a procedure?

The error I get is:

```
PLS-00172: string literal too long
```

This error is thrown after running my test script to test my procedure:

```
declare 
in_json clob;
begin
   -- Call the procedure
   in_json := 'very long json String';
   EA_JAMIE.set_FDC_Data(in_json => in_json);
end;
```

How do I split my input json in chunks ? I never worked with clobs and maybe the answers I found for this error are also applyable for my case but I can't figure out how. PL/SQL is also a fairly new thing for me.

Comment: 49k characters will fit into a clob. upper limit for clob is around 2gb, I think. You're probably implicitly converting your string to varchar2 somewhere.

Comment: @KirillLeontev I think CLOB is near to 4GB. Still even with 2GB it's enough for a 49k characters. I agree with the other part.

Comment: It would be better if you provided the full procedure so it will be easier to debug.

Comment: I added the procedure, thank you all for your help!

Comment: Is elmos_opt any type you have created?

Comment: `v_elseNr VARCHAR(10);` ... `v_elseNr := v_json_keys.get(i).get_string;` - check this one. can the key be longer than 10?

Comment: The full error stack should give you the line number where the error is occurring. Can you add this to the questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is that your *literal* is too long.  A literal can only contain 4000 characters.  Literal here means the value you are setting in_json to before calling your procedure.  You cannot have this:

```
in_json := 'some text that is longer than 4000 characters';
```

See the Oracle documentation about the max length for literals (and other fields) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903).

You can cheat by appending small chunks of your literal together into a CLOB and then passing that into your procedure.  Here is a dumb example.  You would cut your 49k character JSON into 4k character chunks, maybe using NP++ or some text editor to insert a new-line every 4000 characters, then make a variable per chunk, and then append them together.  You can probably even ditch the variables and put the literals directly into the to_clob(), but that's going to make this hack even worse (to look at).

```
DECLARE
  v_s1   VARCHAR2(4000) := lpad('x',
                                4000,
                                'x');
  v_s2   VARCHAR2(4000) := lpad('x',
                                4000,
                                'x');
  v_s3   VARCHAR2(4000) := lpad('x',
                                4000,
                                'x');
  v_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => v_clob,
                           cache   => FALSE);
  dbms_lob.append(dest_lob => v_clob,
                  src_lob  => to_clob(v_s1));
  dbms_lob.append(dest_lob => v_clob,
                  src_lob  => to_clob(v_s2));
  dbms_lob.append(dest_lob => v_clob,
                  src_lob  => to_clob(v_s3));

  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.getlength(lob_loc => v_clob));
END;
/
```

I am assuming (hoping) you are doing this as a unit test and that in_json will eventually come from somewhere else.

Edit: You also might want to pass your CLOB in as IN OUT [NOCOPY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/parameter_declaration.htm#CJACJCGJ) instead of just IN.  This will cause (hopefully) PL/SQL to pass the value by reference instead of making a by value copy of the data saving memory and overhead in your program.  You can read about the details of NOCOPY in the Oracle documentation as there are exceptions where it can be ignored.

```
PROCEDURE set_FDC_Data(in_json IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly fine :)

Yes it is just for testing. The actual JSON-String comes from an java-application.
Do I have to split that CLOB in small chunks too or does this error just occure when I set my in_json in the test script?

Comment: No need to split the CLOB.  You are just splitting to get around the string literal limition.  CLOBs can be very large.  I added one other thought to my answer regarding NOCOPY.